# Applying dual conditions in case when in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, case-when, dbvisualizer

(question edited) My table has `id,status,date,sequence`

Situation: Get ids which satisfies:

- `date` is max, not more than today's **and** `status` is A
- if more than 1 status' with same `date` then get id only if it has max `sequence`

I am writing `MYSQL` in `dbVisulizer`.

edit: trying with query:

```html
select id, max(date), max(sequence) from 
table
where
table.date<=now() and status='A'
order by date desc,sequence desc
```

*It sounds like I am just asking direct question without trying anything by myself, but for this situation I am completely stuck, I tried with `case when` but couldn't really accomplish any good, any starting point would be appriciated.*

Comment: Post whatever you have tried instead posting a requirement. voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, max(date), max(sequence) from 
table
where
table.date<=now() and status='A'
order by date desc,sequence desc
group_by id;
```

This should give you the desired results. Adapt table and field names to your table and fields.

Comment: thanks @Lelio `now()` and `limit` are not supported(dbvisualizer 6.5.1), also I guess your query will limit the result to just one record. Rest looks promising..not sure it is correct

Comment: also needs to `group by` on `id`, to use `max` (an aggregate function)

Comment: ehm... this is not a problem of the tool you are using. Syntax is related to the db engine you are using. now() and limit are supported by mysql and are basic functionalities. Anyway you can skip the limit 1 part and pass the date as a parameter instead of using noww

Comment: group_by is used to return more than one row (one for each project_id in your case) in case of aggregate functions like max. Without a sqlfiddle or the exact table and data structure I can just give you some hints on how to get to your point

Comment: getting error `id is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81179/discussion-between-anil-bhaskar-and-lelio-faieta).

Answer (score 0):

```
select id from 
table
where
table.date<now() and table.status='A'
order by date desc,sequence desc
limit 1;
```

You should check it for mistakes by yourself.